# Error when communicate with WCF-Service via https in Silverlight 4

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, https

in my Silverlight 4 application, I want to consume a WCF-Service via https and User Authentication. I have created and published a test service, which is running at https://pcai043.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/ServiceConfiguratorDataSource/Service.svc

Then I added the service reference to my silverlight project in VS2010 and VS created the appropriate classes. Then I tried to call the Service:

```
private void ButtonTest_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  WCFDataProvider.ServiceClient proxy = new WCFDataProvider.ServiceClient();
  proxy.GetDataCompleted += new EventHandler<WCFDataProvider.GetDataCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_GetDataCompleted);
  proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "theName";
  proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "thePwd";
  proxy.GetDataAsync(10);
}

void proxy_GetDataCompleted(object sender, WCFDataProvider.GetDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show(e.Result, "WCF Service Call", MessageBoxButton.OK);
}
```

When I call the service, I get the following exception: "Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application"

Laufzeitfehler in Microsoft JScript: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Während des Vorgangs ist eine Ausnahme aufgetreten, sodass das Ergebnis ungültig ist. 
Weitere Ausnahmedetails finden Sie in InnerException.
bei System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
   bei ServiceConfiguratorWebPrototyp.WCFDataProvider.GetDataCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
   bei ServiceConfiguratorWebPrototyp.MainPage.proxy_GetDataCompleted(Object sender, GetDataCompletedEventArgs e)
   bei ServiceConfiguratorWebPrototyp.WCFDataProvider.ServiceClient.OnGetDataCompleted(Object state)

This error is thrown by the aspx-page which contains my silverlight app. VS opens a new tab labeled "eval code [dynamical]" which contains nothing but a line that throws the above error.

Any idea, what might cause this error and/or how to find out more details about it? I set breakpoints at proxy_GetDataCompleted, private void OnGetDataCompleted(object state) and string ServiceConfiguratorWebPrototyp.WCFDataProvider.IService.EndGetData(System.IAsyncResult result) in the Reference.cs file, but it doesn't stop at any of those lines.

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: Your exception translated to english says: During the process, an exception has occurred, so the result is invalid. For more details, see the exception in the InnerException.  What does the inner exception say?

Comment: That's the problem. I don't have (found) any way to examine the exception, because the message is only shown, when the Silverlight-App has passed the message to the aspx or html site containing the App. It's merely a text string that is displayed in the mentioned "eval code [dynamical]" page, VS creates when the error occures

Comment: Ok, found it. You need to enable the Silverlight-Debug Option in the Web tab of the Property-Page of the Web-Project (why on earth isn't this automatically checked? What kind of developer wouldn't want the debugger to stop where the error occures?). Now I get a nice description "Security Error". Short but painful. I will have a further look into this now that I know where to look at.

Answer (score 0):

The Silverlight-Debug Option has to be enabled in the Web-Tab of the Configuration of the Website that contains the Silverlight-Application